# Saving to database in Ruby on Rails without printing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and am working on a finance app to aggregate all of my spending. I am collecting all of my data through a form, then showing it all in a different file called show.html.erb. I want to add up all of my spending in show.html.erb, and have so far been able to do it like so:

```
<strong>Total:</strong> 
<td><%= @article.total = (@article.checking_accounts + @article.savings_accounts - @article.debt) %></td>
<td><%= @article.save %></td>
```

However, because the .save command returns a boolean, I am getting my result on my webpage followed by "true" i.e. "544 true" rather than just 544. How do I save to the database without printing to my webpage?

Comment: I'm just reviewing first post from new contribitors, but if I recall "<%=" is an instruction to display, "<%" without does not display the result.  In terms of good practise, having your view do the calculations seems a bit odd, it might be preferable to create a method in your article class that does that calculation on the fly so that just takes that formula and calculates the answer each time, and them you call that method (and doesn't bother saving it.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put `@article.save` inside your view, it should be in your controller, or a callback in your model, but since you just starting, I think, for a quick temporary solution, you can do this:

```
<% @article.total = (@article.checking_accounts + @article.savings_accounts - @article.debt) %>
<% @article.save %>

<strong>Total:</strong> 
<td><%= @article.total %></td>
```

You can use `<% ...%>` if you want the process to run but do not want it to print. You can use `<%= ... %>` if you want to print the value.

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you should try to have the least amount of logic in your views. 
Normally saving data is done by the Create action in a Controller. So, you should have something like this in your controller:

```rb
# articles_controller.rb
...
def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.total = @article.checking_accounts + @article.savings_accounts - @article.debt
  @article.save
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
...
```

And this in your view:

```rb
# show.html.erb
...
<strong>Total:</strong> 
<td><%= @article.total %></td>
...
```